# Light diffusion in Inkscape

Tags: svg, 3d, vector-graphics, inkscape, light

For a little project of mine, I am working on creating a resource pack similar to the package found [here](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/free-pack-of-realistic-vintage-light-bulb-sign-letters). Essentially it is a pack of letters which have light bulbs to light the text. You can see an example below.

[image: Large capital A]

As you can see in this example the light diffuses around each light bulb to make the effect of the light illuminating the rest of the A. My question is what is the best way to create a similar light diffusion effect in Inkscape?

Comment: filters: feDiffuseLighting etc.